# Where to place Unix Domain (AF_UNIX) sockets' end points (files)?

Tags: sockets, unix, posix, unix-socket, fhs

Is there a convention where to place the 'files' representing the end points to Unix Domain Sockets?

I tend to put them to `/tmp/some-application-specific-subdir-name/`, but I wonder if there is a more common place.

The background is, that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_un.h.html) is not clear about the *maximum* path length to *access* such 'files':

> The size of sun_path has intentionally been left undefined. This is because different implementations use different sizes. For example, 4.3 BSD uses a size of 108, and 4.4 BSD uses a size of 104. Since most implementations originate from BSD versions, the size is typically in the range 92 to 108.
>
> Applications should not assume a particular length for sun_path or assume that it can hold {_POSIX_PATH_MAX} bytes (256).

So this "restriction" on the path's length should be kept out of the application's file/path name configurations.

Comment: related: [Idiomatic location for file based sockets on Debian systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88083/366064) on Unix & Linux StackExchange

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) says: [`/run`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html)

(It used to be [`/var/run`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s13.html).)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to FHS, as I missed it. Anyway writing to /var/run normaly isn't possible for ordinary users, as it's not for the application in question. So, is there an alternative to /var/run?

Comment: @alk, I tend to just put them along with the application's dynamic data.  Which might happen to be in `/tmp`.

Comment: A note from 2019: many distros are now migrating `/var/run` to `/run`.

Comment: Please @JB. update the answer: from 2015 FHS 3.0: "These functions have been **moved to /run**; this directory exists to ensure compatibility with systems and software using an older version of this specification." [Further info](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s13.html)

Comment: Updated to FHS 3.0.
@caligari: you know you're allowed to edit on your own, right?

Comment: `touch /run/hi` gives permission denied error, so I wonder how my user-mode app would create a domain socket there.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Look at `/run/user/$(id -u)/` instead of `/run/`. If you use systemd that directory should exist and be owned by your login’s user:group. :)

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, the `netstat` command shows UNIX Domain Sockets in multiple different places. Some, however a few, in `/var/run`, as JB suggested; most of them in `@/tmp/…` (I believe the `@` designate abstract names, which is Linux specific), and some others in various application's specific places. So in practice, the most common location seems to be in `/tmp`, at least on Ubuntu, which is a rather common platform. Note the `/tmp` location particularly makes sense here, as UDS has to be created by each `bind` and to be deleted afterwards (either when the socket is closed, or when the application exit, or when the application starts the next time and before its next invocation to `bind`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The design decision was taken to make the base path for the UDS files configurable and have it default to `/tmp/`, so the files would go to `/tmp/<app-specific-dir>/`. The platforms in use were Red-Hat-Linux, Suse-Linux and z/Linux.

Answer (score -3):

In Android you can place it in `/dev/socket/`

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.