# pip-installed uWSGI ./python_plugin.so error

Tags: python, uwsgi

I've installed uWSGI using pip and start it up with an XML to load my application. The XML config contains `<plugin>python</plugin>`. On my new server it leads to an error:

```
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3321]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
```

I can find the `.c` and the `.o` versions:

```
sudo find / -name 'python_plugin.c'
/srv/www/li/venv/build/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/plugins/python/python_plugin.c
/srv/www/li/venv/build/uwsgi/plugins/python/python_plugin.c
sudo find / -name 'python_plugin.o'
/srv/www/li/venv/build/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/plugins/python/python_plugin.o
/srv/www/li/venv/build/uwsgi/plugins/python/python_plugin.o
sudo find / -name 'python_plugin.so'
```

But no .so found. My previous system had a uwsgi install through apt-get, but that's really old (and I'm quite sure it uses the pip installed uwsgi normally, but maybe not for shared objects then?)

Some background info:

- Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS
- Python 2.7 (virtualenv)
- I've installed uWSGI in my venv, using the normal `pip install uwsgi` (no `sudo`)

So I'm a tad clueless :( I can't be the only person in the world to have this, right? Should I compile the `.so` objects myself? (If so, how?) Or is there another great solution?

Comment: So... I removed the <plugin>python</plugin> from the xml file and now it loads... but I do not understand why/when it is needed. Still have to check also whether it *really* works now

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Distros should package uWSGI in a modular way, with each feature as a plugin. But when you install using language specific ways (pip, gem...) the relevant language is embedded, so you do not need to load the plugin

Comment: This is the most relevant comment on uwsgi installation out there. Thank you. Here's a useful link to future readers: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/MultiPython

Answer (score 54):

For anyone that is having trouble with this, basically you need to remove lines that state your plugin from your configuration files if you change from a distro package to a pypi or gem install. I was previously using the Ubuntu/Debian package for uwsgi, but it was old so I upgraded to use pip instead.

So, in my configuration .ini file, I had the following line:

```
plugin = python
```

Removing that line fixes the problem.

Comment: A small fyi for people who use the xml instead of the .ini, remove "<plugin>python</plugin>"

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you forgot this command

```
$ apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

If you're using Python3, try this command instead:

```
$ apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

Comment: and under centos rhel - `sudo yum install uwsgi-plugin-python`

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS if you pip installed uwsgi and/or are running virtualenv.  The two versions do not play well together.  Use @Jordan answer.

Comment: Confirmed Oct 2019, virtualenv installs at python 3.7, the plugin comes in at python 3.6.  Results in No module named 'encodings'.

Answer (score 0):

Install all available plugins: `sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugins-all`

Answer (score 0):

As of 6/2018 the `yum` package name was updated from `uwsgi-plugin-python` to `uwsgi-plugin-python2` https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/uwsgi/pull-request/4#

The new install command is therefore `yum install uwsgi-plugin-python2`