# uWSGI is not creating socket in Ubuntu 16 server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to run my website on ubuntu server. I have followed steps from digitalocean as I have their vps server. You can see the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). I need only one server so I have not done second site part. Please my `mkvirtualenv` command created 'Env' folder in `root` instead of home. I don't know how it did but I tried twice by destroying droplet and creating again. It did same both time.

My `/etc/uwsgi/sites/app.ini` file has following codes,

```
[uwsgi]
project = app
uid = root
base = /root
plugins=python3
pyhome=/root/app
chdir = /root/app
home = /root/app
module = app.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/app.sock
chown-socket = root:www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

So each time I try to run usgi server with `sudo uwsgi app.ini --thunder-lock` command I am getting following message with an error.

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from app.ini
open("./python3_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3684]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python3_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.13.1 (64bit) on [Mon Aug  8 04:48:51 2016] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 08 August 2016 04:00:28
os: Linux-4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016
nodename: appserver
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /root/app
your processes number limit is 1896
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app.sock fd 3
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Set PythonHome to /root/app
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f74c576a700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

so my root directory has `Env` folder and inside `Env` there is another folder `appdata` for which contains all virtualenv files. And `root` dir has my `app` folder which contains application files of Django. So can anyone tell me what is wrong in my config?

Comment: I think you've used `sudo` to create the virtual environments. You should create your environments and run your website under a non-root user (and not use `sudo`).

Comment: I have followed exact commands of digitalocean

Answer (score 1):

When building from source (e.g. when installing with pip or make), the python plugin is built-in in the binary. As a consequence there's no `python3_plugin.so` shared library and you don't need the `plugins=python3` line in your uwsgi settings.
A similar question was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941424/1827854).