# Error with uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to load uwsgi configs with:

```
sudo uwsgi --ini /var/www/alpanahub/conf/uwsgi.ini
```

But, I am getting error:

```
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3686]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

My uwsgi.ini looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = alpanahub
projectdomain = alpana.alpanatech.com
base = /var/www/alpanahub

# config
plugins = python
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=alpanahub.settings
pythonpath = /var/www/alpanahub/src/alpanahub
module = alpanahub.wsgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
logto = /var/www/alpanahub/logs/uwsgi.log
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/alpanahub.log
```

Comment: can you paste the uwsgi.ini  here ?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan I have added ini file.

Comment: please install uwsgi plugin using the command sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugins-all

Comment: if it is just  a staging server  then you can use the uwsgi simple conf 
    `master          = true 
     socket          = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
     chmod-socket    = 666
     chdir           = /home/ubuntu/sample
     wsgi-file       = /home/ubuntu/sample/sample/wsgi.py
     virtualenv      = /home/ubuntu/sample_env
     vacuum          = true
     enable-threads  = true
     daemonize= /home/ubuntu/sample/uwsgi.log` you can refer this link to deploy your django app [https://www.sayonetech.com/blog/deploying-django-application-development-server-using-nginx/#.Wciqnk2CzQo]

Comment: remove `plugins = python` from your conf and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip-installed uWSGI ./python\_plugin.so error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936413/pip-installed-uwsgi-python-plugin-so-error)

Comment: @TarunLalwaniyour answer helped. Thank you.