# Where to place ZeroMQ sockets' end point (files)?

Tags: sockets, unix, zeromq, fhs

As answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580346/where-to-place-unix-domain-af-unix-sockets-end-points-files), according to the FHS, Unix Domain (AF_UNIX) sockets' should be placed under `/var/run`

What about ZeroMQ sockets? Where should to place them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The answer to that linked question isn't really correct, as the FHS is talking about Systems programs, which will always have appropriate privileges for `/var/run`, vs. applications which may not. The alternative in the other answer is to use `/tmp/[appdirectory]`, which probably makes the most sense.

(b) For most ZMQ use, this is irrelevant, ZMQ abstracts these details away from you, the developer. The exception is if you're using the [IPC transport](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-ipc) for inter-process communication, which uses a filehandle as the transport mechanism.  Per that link, they point to a location in the `/tmp` directory as well - that example is not likely considered "best practice", but close enough that we can combine it with the first point to say you should probably use `/tmp/[appdirectory]`